# Is there a setting to turn off "You have been un-subscribed" emails?

Tags: civimail

When you unsubscribe in Civi you are generated an email that contains "You have been un-subscribed from the following groups" with a link to re-subscribe.   To be clear this is not the 'double opt in' email. And we do not wish to turn off the unsubscribe feature.  We simply want to stop sending these confirmation emails. Is there a way to do this as a configurable setting in CiviMail?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Administer -> CiviMail -> Headers, Footers, and Automated Messages.  There, you will find the automated email you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: Greyson, so if I disable that item these emails won't be sent out?

Comment: Correct, we disabled this for one of our clients and it does not send, but successfully unsubscribes them from the email.  You can also customize said email message.

Comment: Wow, thanks @Greyson we will give that a try.  I have disabled 3 of these messages for Unsubscribe, Resubscribe and Opt Out

Comment: @Greyson unfortunately Civi is not allowing us to send messages without one of these messages enabled.  If you click on the 'Responses' tab of any mailing you are preparing, you will see the Opt-out, Unsubscribe and Resubscribe messages are required. How do you get around this?